# how to get values of selection row in table and concat them and show them in a input text?

Tags: oracle, oracle-adf

I have oracle adf and jdeveloper .
I want to get values of selection row in table and concat them and show them in a input text .
how can i do it?

Comment: User, tell us your jdev version, please!

Comment: Do you want to concat the row values from only one row?

Comment: I have oracle 11gr2 and JDeveloper 11.1.2.1.0 I.  yes i want to concat the row values from only one selected row and show them in a input text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you can use this code which gets you the current row from the iterator and then from this row the attributes:

```
// Get the data from an ADF tree or table
DCBindingContainer dcBindings = (DCBindingContainer)BindingContext.getCurrent().getCurrentBindingsEntry();

// Get a attribute value of the current row of iterator
DCIteratorBinding iterBind= (DCIteratorBinding)dcBindings.get("testIterator");
String attribute = (String)iterBind.getCurrentRow().getAttribute("field1");
// get other attributes and then concat them
...
```

Timo